# VBA .formula= If() with Cell(x, y) as dynamic reference

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying hard to fix this since some time but I can't on my own apparently.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GesamteListe").Cells(X, 18).Formula = _
                "=If(" & Cells(X, 16) & " " = " " & Cells(X, 17) & ",""fine"",""not fine"")"
```

I want to compare two cells, which are always in column 16 and 17 but both are dynamic by X which is determined by actions before. I can't make him accepting my Cells(X, 16) and  Cells(X, 17) which in the end should look like this (exemplary):

if(P3=Q3;"fine";"not fine")

Pretty easy I guess but I tried various versions and none works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.Address`

```
 "=If(" & Cells(X, 16).Address & "  =  " & Cells(X, 17).Address & ",""fine"",""not fine"")"
```

You also had too many `"` around the `=`

Comment: For curiosity - can you get the `.Address` without the absolute reference? Say OP wants to create that formula in VBA, and then drag down in the Sheet? (...ignore that he can just set the range to have the formula in the code). Edit - Yes you can. I just realized you can do `.Address(false,false)` to keep the row and column not absolute.

Comment: @BruceWayne Do you mean `.Address(False, False)`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @BruceWayne or `.Address(0,0)`

Comment: Thank you! I already tried it with .Address but I probably changed more than that one thing and made a mistake somewhere else. Sometimes you just dont get what you are doing wrong, even if it is simple.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is also a viable alternative to the solution provided by @ScottCraner:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GesamteListe").Cells(x, 18).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=If(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""fine"",""not fine"")"
```

---

Note, in case that `X` is part of a loop of the following type:

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 20
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GesamteListe").Cells(x, 18).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=If(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""fine"",""not fine"")"
Next x
```

the above formula can short-cut this loop with the following formula:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GesamteListe").Range("R2:R20").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=If(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""fine"",""not fine"")"
```

Comment: It is totaly looped here :)